# I am writing a script to embed Youtube or vimeo videos into magento product page

Tags: php, magento, if-statement

Youtube embed code has letters and vimeo embed code has numbers example v?cVxmbd5 and Vimeo is like Vimeo.com/6847539 . I am writing a script to pull the end of embed strings with letters to match it with top iframe and pull end of embed strings with no letters to match with bottom iframe.

This script is supposed to embed videos into a video tab on the product view page.

```
<?php
$_product = $this->getProduct();
if ($_product->getVideo())
$videos = explode(', ', $_product->getVideo());

foreach ($videos as $video) {

if (ctype_digit($video)) {
echo "<iframe width = '560' height = '315' style = 'max-width:100%;' src = 'https://player.vimeo.com/video/" . $video . "' frameborder = '0' allowfullscreen></iframe>";
} else {


  echo "<iframe width = '560' height = '315' style = 'max-width:100%;' src = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/" . $video . "' frameborder = '0' allowfullscreen></iframe>";

}
}

?>
```

Comment: Inspect the element and check the iframe are there or not.

Comment: When I run the code the entire tabbed menu disappears. I'll add pics to the question.

Comment: Can you provide your site URL?

Comment: I found my problem. I should have used ctype_digit function instead. Easier logic.